# Regex to extract first instance of number and replace everything else in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that looks like:

> > **/some/example/path/here/*[somePositiveInteger]*_.000**

where *[somePositiveInteger]* is some positive integer (e.g. 1, 23542, 331232, etc.) and `_.000` can be `_.101`, `_.343`, etc.

I'd like to change this to look something like:

> > **/some/example/path/here/dispform.aspx?id=*[somePositiveInteger]***

I figured I could just extract *[somePositiveNumber]* by splitting the string on `/`, then removing `_.000`, then appending the number back to `/some/example/path/here/dispform.aspx?id=`.

However, this seems like something regex can do more efficiently. How do I do this using regex then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this example:

```
string input = "/some/example/path/here/99999_.000";
input = Regex.Replace(input, @"(.*/)(\d+)_\.\d{3}$", "$1"+"dispform.aspx?id=$2");
```

`$1` holds the whole path before `/` for the regex `(.*/)`

`$2` holds the required digit for the regex `(\d+)`

Comment: Both solutions work for me, so I'll have to give it to who answered first in this case (: Thanks to you and @Timwi

Answer (score 1):

The following method produces the result you describe:

```
static string ConvertPath(string input)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(input, @"^(.*)/(\d+)_\.\d\d\d$");
    if (!match.Success)
        throw new ArgumentException("The input does not match the required pattern.");
    return match.Groups[1].Value + "/dispform.aspx?id=" + match.Groups[2].Value;
}
```

Note that it uses a regular expression to match the pattern, and then constructs a new string from the resulting match. It throws an exception if the input is not in the required form.